# Connect to multiple databases dynamically using Logstash JDBC Input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using Logstash JDBC input plugin to read data from database and index it into Elastic Search. 
I have separate database for each customer and I want to connect to them one by one dynamically to fetch data?

**Is there any provision or parameter in JDBC-Input Plugin or Logstash to connect to multiple databases?**

**e.g**

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB"
    //MYDB will be set dynamically. 
    jdbc_user => "mysql"
    parameters => { "favorite_artist" => "Beethoven" }
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from songs where artist = :favorite_artist"
  }
}
```

**Only solution I can think of** is writing script that will update logstash config to connect to specified databases one by one and run logstash through it.

Comment: maybe the easiest way would be to have multiple jdbc input. How many customers do you have ?

Comment: Approx 500, Customer database server details are stored in one central database.

Comment: @ni3ns did you find a solution for it? I have the same problem statement.

Answer (score -1):

Let me update this - 
for the same kind of purpose, I used two input JDBC sections, but only first section considered.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "XXXX"
        jdbc_user => "XXXX"
        jdbc_password => "XXXX"
        statement => "select * from product"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        }
 jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "YYYY"
        jdbc_user => "YYYYY"
        jdbc_password => "YYYY"
        statement => "select * from product"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        user => "XXX"
        password => "XXXX"
        index => "XXXX"
        document_type => "XXXX"
        }
}
```

--